# Correct way to split quads for terrain made from heightmap?

Tags: opengl, terrain, heightmap

The individual pixels/values in a heightmap only give you a 2D grid of vertices of varying heights, so you have to connect them with quads. That's easy enough if all 4 vertices of a quad are co-planar, but when they aren't you need some splitting rule. One way is to pick the shorter/longer edge, another to use the higher one, etc... Another I've found that works is calculating a center vertex for the quad (average of all 4 heights), though this doubles the number of triangles which is far from optimal.

What's the correct way to split quads? Or is there an alternative to quads?

Answer (score 1):

The general rule is that splits should be aligned to the local surface curvature curl. A simple diagonal split works for surfaces with a Gaussian Curvature of 0 (planes, cylinders), but a midpoint subdivision split refinement is recommended for nonzero Gaussian Curvature.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't use quads at all. For practical terrain heightmaps, heights are never gonna be coplanar, and the GPU don't prefer quads to triangles, in fact, it will internally divide the quad in 2 triangles.

However, I wouldn't care much about the splitting rule. From my experience working in terrain renderers, one of the best things you can do is to have a small 2D triangle mesh tile (like 128x128 vertices) and repeat it as many times as you need, with one heightmap per tile passed as a texture.

The reason behind repeating the same 2D tile instead of a more typical 3D mesh is that memory usage and memory bandwidth will be reduced a lot, because if you use the 3D mesh you'll probably need 3xFP32 values (per vertex) that will be padded to 4xFP32 (128bits), but if you use my 2D tile approach you just need 2xU8 (16 bits) + 1xFP16 (16 bits) = 32 bits. That's a 4x memory bandwidth reduction, memory usage will be even better: 8x less memory usage. Keep in mind that unless you have a very complex fragment shader (unlikely for a terrain renderer), you are gonna be memory bandwidth bottle-necked in most GPUs.

Combine this with quad-trees (for LOD) and with normal maps and you will have a very good quality/performance ratio.

Comment: How is such a 2D triangle mesh meant to work? Can you provide/link to an example? Also when I say quad I mean a pair of two triangles that form a quad, i.e. I do the quad splitting on CPU and render with `GL_TRIANGLES`.

Comment: I don't have a link, but... The 2D triangle mesh is just a mesh like this: http://photos1.blogger.com/blogger2/2483/1050461954730077/320/Mesh.0.jpg It's just a regular mesh, and the splitting is always in the same direction. The height of each vertex would be computed by sampling a 2D texture, the heightmap.